# reverse an array without changing position of zero

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have just tried some of the data structures questions along with my friends. I encountered this problem from one of my friends who is also not able to solve it.

> Question: Reverse an array without changing position of zeroes. example : if array has has 0 5 7 8 0 9 then the result should be 0 9 8 7 0 5.

I tried it but it does not do it correctly in all cases, I am sorry if code looks ugly I am a novice right now.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[100], tot, i, j, temp;
    cout<<"Enter the Size for Array: ";
    cin>>tot;
    cout<<"Enter "<<tot<<" Array Elements: ";
    for(i=0; i<tot; i++)
        cin>>arr[i];
    cout<<"\nThe Original Array is:\n";
    for(i=0; i<tot; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    j = tot-1;
    for(i=0; i<j; i++, j--)
    {
        if(arr[i] == 0) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }else if(arr[j] == 0) {
           j--;
           continue;
        }
        else {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n\nThe Reverse of Given Array is:\n";
    for(i=0; i<tot; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the above code but it does not give the correct results.

Comment: You decrementing/incrementing your indexes in cases where they should remain untouched. For example, when you discover a zero on the `i` positional ascension, only `i` should be incremented, but your increment-step in your for loop then grabs hold and increments `i` *again*, and decrements `j` (which was never used to acquire any data on the prior loop). Talk to your rubber duck about your loop index logic; it probably has some keen insights for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is the fact that you're modifying the loop variables `i` and `j` in every iteration of the loop; you need to update it only in the case of elements being swapped:

```
for(i=0; i<j;)
{
    if(arr[i] == 0) {
        i++;
    }else if(arr[j] == 0) {
       j--;
    }
    else {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
        ++i;
        --j;
    }
}
```

[Demo on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgOykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmZqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfGJtpj2jgJCBEzEBNk%2BflyBdpgOmfWNBMWRMXEJSQoNTS257bbj/WGDZcOJAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMYcjeWADUJrtuTmPEmKxn2CYaAIIPj17pRsdj6CAoYWdWTzeYWAnwI3xQ6wI/xeQI%2BXx%2Brlo0KeLzCBGOLCYYQgyxeJn8AMex2JxzRx0axBMAFYLFwNBpqQARUjHIgEFl4FnaFkETAsZLIokktBeKHnM5ucxmbCCOKshCYY5CPAAL0V/GIx0exGITAAniBTolBSTjsg/rt7pa2SbhZCJQ7EjLeZqpQ7zjbxeLElqdfrjth6GxBApDW7doTTRqIHgzoyGRHSRLPRYk5ZrLinqbTeaGHc7hTqRZY1TGbbiSKxZLvWZqW4GAAVBXHADyxDwwDCYl9ur1pNDdbzxojLyjJBjcYTqdjHtQYun1gzo%2BzFftXrchZpJbL66lRtrI6zJO0p12jNZc4AtFxy8dozP4/8k%2BdtP9M0LifjIyvSVQIJviyZU8d3PDRllOAllx/ElY3TdNDw/bN8UZaolF/f8dSLV9S2AuNjjAiDv2g45tEvS9b1NZCoOzVDFS/ajoN5flgPJTCtyZCifwA7cWIA7CdyI4i%2BKAvCmIFBDiJJRdLBnQToLI18JJ/Kij0/fwy1Us012rSVjSpetBybRUACVMAANziNDUCoY4AHE8Ashge39PAB30ocD0E%2B9JyfGc3BTNMrEsd9oMrd0NzYwDS3Cvdw0EsL10RW9rgIDYnKnPF1I4VZaE4KleD8DgtFIVBOF0oLUwUdZNjosxdh4UgCE0bLVgAaxASQAE4ADoADZOt2MwqS4Kldl2fxJDq6Rco4SReBYCR6VIQritKjheFDDRGua1Y4FgJBMFULpRRIchKEaYAFGUQxqiEBBUAAd0Khq0H5OgmFqBhrvCWg7selbeFe5I6GGYAuEqIGQeIFtRT%2Bp7mqCI7kG1S7OF4Q6unqfBCt6l4NGOKljn8Y4AA58OOTreH4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQip0PQDCMFBpJsWg8GiUNIFWVBkk%2B0MOEvFszGOS8AHUxFoGXkkwdBDEcZAZaoBRDAyNU4yYdB0GuBQFBlkFLy%2BONTDg2kGqqjYtj0L4wm%2B277vhtnGuubYGoe3Vkk4HgcrygqEbW7AkZOzVVBJ3rL16yRjmAZANfB7rpYgcrrBZXBCBII16uWXgmrZ5Y2pAKkNG63YNF6iaSckXreqG/wm96/RODm5aw7R2wQC2kutDLjuODMUPPbW4udtWCziHSZxJCAA)

Comment: @YvesDaoust the `continue` statements didn't do anything, since on all branches they were the last statement of the loop body for a given iteration.

Comment: You are right, my bad. In fact this is probably the best solution, as it uses a single loop.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need the next logic inside the loop:

```
i = 0;
j = tot-1;
while(i<j)   {
        while (arr[i]==0 && i<j)
            i++;
        while (arr[j]==0 && j>i) 
           j--;
        if (i < j) {
          temp = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[j];
          arr[j] = temp;
        }
       i++;
       j--; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two pointers to switch, simply skipping any 0's.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[100], tot, i, j, temp;
    cout<<"Enter the Size for Array: ";
    cin>>tot;
    cout<<"Enter "<<tot<<" Array Elements: ";
    for(i=0; i<tot; i++)
        cin>>arr[i];
    cout<<"\nThe Original Array is:\n";
    for(i=0; i<tot; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    i = 0, j = tot-1;
    while (i < j) {
        if (arr[i]!=0 && arr[j]!=0) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        } else if (arr[i] == 0) {
            i++;
        } else {
            j--;
        }
    }
   
    cout << "\n Reverse all elements of the array: " << endl;  
    // use for loop to print the reverse array  
    for ( i = 0; i < tot; i++)  
    {  
        cout << arr[i] << " ";  
    }  
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can see this in action here: https://godbolt.org/z/84q3McccW

Answer (score 0):

In your code in the loop:

```
    if(arr[i] == 0) {
        i++;
        continue;
    }else if(arr[j] == 0) {
       j--;
       continue;
```

You increment `i` when `arr[i]` is a `0`. But then you `continue` and for the next iteration `i` is incremented again as part of `i++, j--`.  This makes your code skip elements.
I suggest to use `std::vector` and iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x{1,2,0,3,4,0,0,0};
    auto begin = x.begin();
    auto end = std::prev(x.end());

    while (begin != end) {
        while(begin != end && *begin == 0) ++begin;
        while(begin != end && *end == 0) --end;    
        if (begin != end) {
            std::swap(*begin,*end);
            ++begin;
            if (begin != end) --end;
        }
    }
    for (const auto& e : x) std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

[output](https://godbolt.org/z/hn5dfx8cK):

```
4 3 0 2 1 0 0 0
```

The code starts with iterators to first and last element. In the loop they are advanced while they refer to a `0` and the two didn't cross each other yet. Then the elements are swapped.

If additional memory is acceptable, a much simpler solution is to copy all non zero elements to a second `std::vector`, `std::reverse` that vector, then copy back. Alternatively use the ranges library with a filter.

Answer (score 0):

If there were no zeroes to be skipped, the code could be

```
for (i= 0, j= n-1; i < j; i++, j--)
{
  Swap(a[i], a[j]);
}
```

Now it "suffices" to skip the zeroes. This gives the modified code

```
for (i= 0, j= n-1; i < j; i++, j--)
{
  while (i < j && a[i] == 0) i++;
  while (i < j && a[j] == 0) j--;
  Swap(a[i], a[j]);
}
```

Notice that the Swap can be performed with i==j, which is useless but harmless, as 0 ≤ i ≤ j < n.

---

Update: as done by @fabian, you can compress the three loops in one.

```
for (i= 0, j= n-1; i < j; )
{
  if (a[i] == 0) 
    i++;
  else if (a[j] == 0) 
    j--;
  else
  { 
    Swap(a[i], a[j]);
    i++; j--;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to change the logic of reverse.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[100], tot, i, j, temp;
    cout<<"Enter the Size for Array: ";
    cin>>tot;
    cout<<"Enter "<<tot<<" Array Elements: ";
    for(i=0; i<tot; i++)
        cin>>arr[i];
    cout<<"\nThe Original Array is:\n";
    for(i=0; i<tot; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    j = tot-1;
   for ( i = 0, j = tot - 1; i < tot/2; i++, j--)  
    {     
        temp = arr[i];  
        arr[i] = arr[j];  
        arr[j] = temp;  
    }  
    cout << "\n Reverse all elements of the array: " << endl;  
    // use for loop to print the reverse array  
    for ( i = 0; i < tot; i++)  
    {  
        cout << arr[i] << " ";  
    }  
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this will help

Comment: doesnt produce correct results https://godbolt.org/z/3saz9KKEn

Comment: your code isnt taking into account the 0s at all...